# How to generate only one single XML result with jasmine-report and protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I have one single protractor project with following dependencies in packages.json:

- 'protractor'
- 'grunt-protractor-runner'
- 'grunt-jasmine-node'
- 'jasmine-reporters'

I have this protractor-config:

```
exports.config =
  specs: [
    'build/test/e2e/**/*_spec.js'
  ]

capabilities:
browserName: "chrome"

onPrepare: () ->
    require('jasmine-reporters')
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter("test/reports/e2e", 
                                 false, true))
```

1. It ran 20 tests and they finished properly, but under the "test/reports/e2e" directory multiple XML files were generated (1 XML file is generated per test). How can I generate results of these 20 tests into one only xml file, like this?

> ```
> <testsuite ....>
>     <testcase classname="..." name="..." time="0.008"/>
>     <testcase classname="..." name="..." time="0.002"/>
>     <testcase classname="..." name="..." time="0.108"/>
>     <testcase classname="..." name="..." time="0.004"/>
>     <testcase classname="..." name="..." time="0.002"/>
> </testsuite>
> ```

2. Is there a framework or plugin for translating this XML result into a readable format (e.g. html)

Note: I am not using mocha nor karma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JUnitXmlReporter()` and `JUnit` format specifically was not designed to be read by humans. It is a specific format that your Continuous Integration server (like `jenkins`) knows how to understand, parse and show readable results.

If you want to see an HTML report, there is [`protractor-html-screenshot-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter) package.